# Android getSupportActionbar() is Null when Activity is called from tabhost

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I have a support action bar that works fine if I trigger the event with an intent manually. But if I leave it up to the tabhost to call it then the actionbar returned from getSupportActionbar() is null.

I've heard this referenced on Stack in another question, but no one has supplied and answer. (Apparently it only occurs on Android 3 and above).  Does anyone have any ideas?

My tabhost:

```
public class NavTab extends TabActivity {

    TabHost tabHost;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab);

        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();  // The activity TabHost
        TabHost.TabSpec spec;  // Resusable TabSpec for each tab
        Intent intent;  // Reusable Intent for each tab

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, SummaryPage.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Summary");
        spec.setIndicator("Account", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon_summary));
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        //Feedback
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, FeedbackPage.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Feedback");
        spec.setIndicator("Feedback", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon_summary));
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        //Payment Locations
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, PaymentLocationsActivity.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Payment Locations");
        spec.setIndicator("Pay Loc", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon_summary));
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        //Usage Alert
        intent = new Intent().setClass(this, UsageAlertPage.class);
        spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Usage Alerts");
        spec.setIndicator("Alerts", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_icon_summary));
        spec.setContent(intent);
        tabHost.addTab(spec);

        tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);

    }


}
```

My activity

```
public class PageWithActionBar extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener {

    private static String TAG = "mymeter-Main";
    private List<Account> accounts = new LinkedList<Account>();
    private LocationAdapter locationAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

        accounts.add(new Account("123456789", "4-15 Rose Rd", "Auckland 1021"));
        accounts.add(new Account("0987654321", "49 Ronaki Rd", "Auckland 1043"));
        locationAdapter = new LocationAdapter(this, accounts);
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(locationAdapter, this);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your TabActivity needs to extend `SherlockActivity`, check out the ActionBarSherlock samples on Tabs

- [TabNavigation](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/TabNavigation.java)
- [FragmentTabs](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/FragmentTabs.java)

Comment: Can i use this sherlock things, when i already have a Sherlock action bar? Because I want to have an Actionbar at the top, then tabs below it

Comment: Yeah, those examples I liked to are samples from the ActionBarSherlock project showing how tabs can be used.  One thing I think you'll run into with having the ActionBar at the top and the tabs below is that in landscape mode on large screens or on tablets the Tabs can be folded in to the ActionBar to they take up less vertical space.